# Редактирование массива json в java

Tags: java, android

Я совсем новичок в java. Есть задача - приложение под android для редактирования json файла.
Конкретно - json содержит массив вида [339247963, 304480994, 459359273, 542871765], нужно добавить в него еще одно значение. Нужно скачать файл с сервера, добавить id, загрузить обратно. Приложение - не проблема, главное отредактировать массив.

Comment: А как Вы пытались редактировать массив? Что у Вас конкретно не получилось

Comment: я не особо пытался, т.к. не знаю как(

Comment: Представляю, как вы будете скачивать файл, редактировать и снова загружать, раз такую простую задачу не знаете как сделать. Используйте `Json` пакет.

Comment: Скачать и загрузить не проблема, у меня уже получилось.

Comment: Исходя из конструкции json то это jsonarray я бы вам посоветовал воспользоваться JsonArray из библиотеки Gson.

Comment: @KeiMoger, Вы хоть покажите что у Вас получилось. Во что Вы преобразовали ответ сервера? Как давать ответ без кода - тоже на словах?

Comment: Уже всё сделал, пришлось попотеть. Сервер ответ не шлет, нужно было скачать файл, отредактировать и загрузить обратно.

Answer (score 0):

Смотрим документацию [`JSONArray`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html) и пишем:

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(responseString); // аргумент может быть строкой, массивом, коллекцией
array.put(newElement);
String requestBody = array.toString();
// здесь можем слать строку requestBody на сервер
```